# iOS Localization: Create strings-file for native language?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, string, localization

If you're an English programmer and write your code like...

```
NSLocalizedString(@"Hello", ...)
```

... do you create a `en.lproj/Localizable.strings` although there's the same string in there as in the NSLocalizedString macro?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, no, you don't need to if you use the string as the key to `NSLocalizedString`. But you can then use the `Localizable.strings` file to replace strings in the UI without changing the code files.

Also, you don't have to use the actual string as the key to `NSLocalizedString`, you could use a set of generic identifiers for the purpose (like the comment parameter is intended to help with). Then you need the `Localizable.strings` file to fill in the true UI values.

Answer (score 0):

The best tutorial on Localization I found is by Ray Wenderlich: [How to localize an iphone app](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/how-to-localize-an-iphone-app-tutorial)

Comment: I think this doesn't really relate to my problem, but thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

First, the Apple docs answer your question in the [Foundations Functions Reference for NSLocalizedString](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/macro/NSLocalizedString) when it reads "The initial value for `key` in the strings file will be `key`."

Second, this question is ranked high in my searches, so I'd like to add 1 situation in which I **do** create a strings file in my native language/locale.

My native language/locale is English. I create a strings file for programmatically generated singular nouns that I sometimes need to pluralize. Example:

```
@interface XYZFeline : NSObject
...
@interface XYZCanine : NSObject
...
@implementation XYZAnimalController
NSDictionary *classToWord = @{ @"XYZFeline": @"cat", @"XYZCanine" : @"dog" };

- (NSString *)describeQuantityOfAnimal:(id)animal
{
    NSString *typeWord = classToWord[NSStringFromClass(animal)];
    NSString *sentence = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %lu %@.",
        NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"You have", @"phrases.strings", nil),
        animal.count,
        [animal.count == 1
            ? NSLocalizedStringFromTable(typeWord, @"nouns.strings", nil)
            : NSLocalizedStringFromTable(typeWord, @"nouns-plural.strings", nil),
    ];
    return sentence;
}
```

The `nouns.strings` for English does not exist, but the English `nouns-plural.strings` file looks like this:

```
"dog" = "dogs";
"cat" = "cats";
```

Example output:

```
You have 3 dogs.
You have 1 cat.
```

This will allow you to get proper singular or plural nouns in your output without putting language rules in your code.

*Note:* I am aware that my coded sentence structure of subject, predicate, object and adjective-before-noun is limited to only some Indo-European languages, but that is a problem to solve in another question.